# When is it sensible to catch NullPointerException?

Tags: java

I think most of the time, if not always, we can avoid null pointer exceptions by checking if an object is null before sending it a message.

When is it sensible then to catch NullPointerException instead of checking for null pointers?

Comment: I wonder why this question is marked duplicate and not the other one (which was asked later). Is it because the other one has more useful information for people who visit the site?

Comment: Because if that's the case, then when an earlier question is marked as duplicate, it also implies that the OP didn't look around enough before asking, which is not true here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While technically a RuntimeException such as NullPointerException is the same as checked exceptions like IOException, their philosophy is very different. In short, checked exceptions are there to allow handling of issues that are out of the programmers control, such as network failures or missing files. The intended use of unchecked exceptions is to catch programming errors.

Given that they are there to catch programming errors, NullPointerException and other unchecked exceptions should almost never be caught. Instead the programming error that allowed them to be thrown should be fixed.

Comment: I don't really see the difference of checking for null vs. checking for missing files. Neither are *really* any more "out of the programmer's control" than the other. Especially if you are using library code that might return null at any point (even when it claims it won't). In reality it does happen.

Comment: If you derefence a null, it's because you wrote code to deference it. If a file is missing it may well be because the user removed it.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't write all the code you use. If a function returns null it may well be because they didn't bother documenting that behaviour. It's a similar problem to C-style init functions returning pointers to objects that you don't know who is responsible for freeing - the interface isn't enough to specify the behaviour, and documentation is often lacking. Same with weakly typed languages. C++ (for example) doesn't really have this problem. At least not nearly so bad.

Comment: The question was about checking for null in code you write.

Comment: It's about "checking if an object is null before sending it a message". Hard to do that in code you didn't write.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I mean you don't write all the code *you use*, so sometimes you might be using a value that you *think* shouldn't ever be `null`, but due to poor library code/documentation could occasionally be `null`. Either you have to check every single function call (insane) or catch NPEs or be happy with occasional crashes. Other languages get around this problem by having types that can't be `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Checking for null is the best way to go. I never catch for NPE. In fact I always try to not send null from my methods rather do a "return Collections.emptyList();" so the caller does not have to check for null.

Comment: Unless null actually has meaning.

Comment: I am sure it's a matter of opinion. But I personally don't see the point for someone to code for NULL as a legal return value.

Comment: What about `Map.get(Object)`?

Comment: Touche Willi. thanks for an excellent example.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO never. Catching NPE is much more costly (in memory and processor time) then checking for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

As other has said, it's better to check for null rather than catching it. The only time, in my opinion, you will catch NullPointerException is when some API that you call and you have no control over is throwing that particular exception. Then, it makes sense to catch NullPointerException and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's right, it is more costly.  Though there are cases where you wouldn't want to bother checking and just catch the null pointer, such as implementing a scripting language interpreter on the JVM. Expression evaluation code would just get way too messy if you were checking for null everywhere.